# Home Template Loop customization - should fetch content based on post template

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

In the theme there are two files:

1. single.php
2. `f-template.php` →  For default post type. It has different designs.

`Home.php` will fetch first 10 posts, and they can be among any of the above templates.

But, what is needed is when the content on home.php is coming from `f-template.php`

then these two things should be implemented on home.php

```
function folder_paragrapgh($content){
        return preg_replace('/<p([^>]+)?>/', '<p class="para para2">', $content);
        }
        add_filter('the_content', 'folder_paragrapgh');
```

and

```
<script>
    (function($) {
        // do all your $ based jquery in here.
        $(function() {
          $('p.class2').prepend('<img src="http:/sample.com/img/folder.svg" width="50" height="25" alt="">');
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

I tried this:

```
if( is_page_template( 'f-template.php' ) ) {

    function folder_paragrapgh($content){
        return preg_replace('/<p([^>]+)?>/', '<p class="para para2">', $content);
        }
        add_filter('the_content', 'folder_paragrapgh');
    }

    the_content();
}
```

But this didn't work. actually it is flawed because the template that we are dealing is `home.php`.

So do we have any solution to achive what we wanted to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it sounds like you want to display a loop with posts where some posts have a different design depending on the Page Template you have selected for it.

You can check which template is being used with the [get_page_template_slug() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_template_slug/). Use it inside the loop along with the ID of the post.

```php
// checks if there are any posts that match the query
if (have_posts()) :

    // If there are posts matching the query then start the loop
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        // Assign postId from within the loop
        $postId = the_ID();

        if( get_page_template_slug($postId) === 'f-template' ) {
            // Display what you want to see when f-template is selected.

        } else {
            // Display what you want to see by default if no condition is met.

        }

    // Stop the loop when all posts are displayed
    endwhile;

// If no posts were found
else :

    echo '<p>Sorry no posts matched your criteria.</p>';

endif;
```

The [is_page_template() function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/) won't work because it will check what the page template for the current page in the Main Query is.

It all depends on your use case but personally I would have added an extra field using Advanced Custom Fields for this effect.

Good luck!

Comment: Your understanding about the problem is correct. Can you write a full solution with its usage → get_page_template_slug(

Comment: Can we fix it somehow w/o the custom field. Just aking `home.php` more intelligent?

Comment: I've added a code example you can use within the loop. Replace $postId by the variable you are using. Just putting in the $post object should work too.

Comment: what is $postId? ID of some particular post? because posts from that template can be many we can't just put one ID. I am a beginner please bear with me.

Comment: No worries. What I meant to say is that when you use the WordPress loop you get access to a function called the_ID(). You can put its value inside a variable and then use that variable to check which template is used with the get_page_template_slug function.

I updated the code to make it clear it's used inside the loop. To make this clear further. The loop is run for every post that's passed in. So for every post the $postID variable will be changed and used.